# Ipad hover event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to create a false hover event for my site using jQuery...

I have created the following only all the child elements in my list now return false also as opposed to linking to the correct page...

```
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i))) {
    $("ul.sf-menu li.i").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

Has anybody an idea on an alternative method that could work?

---

HTML

```
<ul class="sf-menu"> <li><a href="index.html">Home</a><li class="i"><a href="wedding-hire.html">Weddings</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="peel-suite.html">Peel Suite</a></li>
                <li><a href="the-hall.html">The Hall</a></li>
                <li><a href="the-grounds.html">The Grounds</a></li>
                <li><a href="food-and-drink.html">Food &amp; Drink</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricing.html">Pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

Comment: There is no hover on mobile devices. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I know @Danwellman, Im trying to create the effect, by showing the child UL on click as opposed to linking through to the parent page

Answer (score 0):

well. without HTML its kind of hard to tell. But you are stopping the default behavior of the browser when the user clicks on the li (and therefor also its children, which I suppose is an anchor/link).
you could check if its a link or an anchor on click and handle it differently;

```
$("ul.sf-menu li.i").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target.nodeName!=="A"){
        e.preventDefault();
        //do your hover code
    }
    else{
        //do nothing, because the user wants the link to load
    }
});
```

Comment: try out my code and where it says "do your hover code", unhide/show the ul of the submenu.

Answer (score 0):

change youre selector so it only matches the first level of listpoints, also i dont see a class i so you might need to drop that from the selector aswell.

```
$("ul.sf-menu > li")
```

Comment: sorry forgot the event bubbles from the child listpoints, simple solution is just to bind a e.stopPropagation() on the children

   $("ul.sf-menu li").click(,function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation()
   })